# Confidence intervals for odds ratio of fixed effects with CLMM2 in R package ordinal

Tags: r, logistic-regression, mixed-models, confidence-interval, ordinal

I am using the package [ordinal](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/index.html) in R to run ordinal logistic regression mixed models on ordinal data with 4 categories.
I have to use `clmm2` because one of my explanatory variables does not satisfy the proportional odds assumption and the nominal effects are not available in `clmm`. However, I do not know how to extract the confidence interval for the odds ratio of the fixed effects with `clmm2`.

For `clmm`, I understand that confidence intervals of the odds ratio are obtained by transforming the limits of confidence intervals of the parameter estimates, provided by the `confint` method as shown below using the wine dataset:

```
require(ordinal)
fm1 <- clmm(rating ~ contact + temp + (1|judge), data = wine)
round(exp(confint(fm1)), 2)
```

However, for `clmm2`, the `confint` method only provides confidence intervals for the standard deviation of the random effects, and not for the fixed effects (here contact and temp, with the proportional odds assumption relaxed for contact in our example).

```
fm2 <- clmm2(rating ~ temp, nominal = ~ contact, random = judge, data = wine, Hess = TRUE)
pr2 <- profile(fm2)
confint(pr2)
```

Do you know any other method to obtain the confidence intervals for the fixed effects with `clmm2`? I have not been able to find the answer to this question anywhere.

Comment: Did you get any answer? This is also my doubt

Comment: Hi @FranBraga,
I got an answer from Rune Haubo on the [ordinal Github page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/index.html).

Comment: Linking to [actual answer](https://github.com/runehaubo/ordinal/issues/25) for benefit of others